# jQuery width() returning same value for all elements in mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am calculating the width of all the elements with a class, on desktop this works fine(all total width is 2862) and I get an exact figure. On mobile however all elements are seen to have the same width(290px) causing the overflow of the scroll to take up 2 lines.

```
var daywidth = 0;
$(".timetable-day").each(function(){
    daywidth += $(this).outerWidth();
});
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7j8kskf0/

I have tried width, outerwidth and this.offsetWidth(normal javascript) and I don't know what is causing this problem. Any help would be great.I am using bootstrap 3.

Comment: Show more code please. Preferably a fiddle too.

Comment: added the JS fiddle of all relevant code.

Comment: Works in Android/Firefox, with 10px more (daywidth += 20;) it works in Android/Chrome, too. Test it here: http://pascha.org/test/test.php

Comment: I tried it on iOS with daywidth += 200 and it still doesn;t display correct width.

Comment: So, a riddle: Which one of the 10000 iOS Safari HTML implementation bugs is causing this behaviour?

Comment: Is this a common problem? Thanks for testing in android. I looked through a list of bootstrap CSS and couldn't find any classes I used.

Comment: hm.. well i tested http://pascha.org/test/test.php on an iphone6 without problems. i show the growth of the value of "daywidth" in the lower div. try it yourself. your problem seems to be something else, but not this code.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted here is working on Android & iOS.
See for yourself: http://pascha.org/test/test.php

Your Problem must be somewhere else.

Possible thoughts: 
In bootstrap some classes expand to 100% width on mobile browsers.
I think you may have used one of these classes.

OR You have changed some style for mobile output and dont remember;-)

Comment: Thanks for this but I am blocked from viewing this in work, the reason is "Extremist Groups".

Comment: LOL? this is my private domain on my VPS... Oh wait, there is a Counter-Strike clanpage on it. Which country you are from, that blocks Counter-Strike clanpages bc of "Extremist groups"? o0

Comment: ok seems it is common in schools and workplaces nowadays to block through filter searches. i talked to a trainee in our company and he says the same happens in his school (germany, land of the _real_ free). they block ppl from surfing on gamesites. unfair!

Comment: The country of Scotland, I work in a college, the head of IT is really strict and probably enforced the maximum security settings

Comment: yeah, first time i read it i didnt notice you said "at work". in my twisted head i thought you were from USA and they block sites with words like "bombs" or "explosive" ^^ that said i deleted the site, the clan and server dont exist anymore. as time goes by..

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found from this was to give the timetable-inner/inner scroll div a min-width of 3000px in css, then modify the javascript:

```
    $(".timetable-inner").css("min-width", daywidth + "px");
```

This works as expected. The space gives all the elements the ability to go on the same line then the JavaScript shrinks the div.